# Typescript recursive generics struggling with conditional types

Tags: typescript, generics

The following code compiles:

```
type Ugh = {
  boo: {[s: string]: Ugh },
  baz: ({ [P in keyof Ugh["boo"]]: Ugh["boo"][P] extends Ugh ? Ugh["boo"][P] : string })
};

const q: Ugh = { boo: {}, baz: {}};
const v: Ugh = {boo: { why: { boo: {}, baz: {}}}, baz: { why: { boo: {}, baz: {}} }};
```

whereas the following doesn't

```
type Ugh = {
  boo: {[s: string]: string | Ugh },
  baz: ({ [P in keyof Ugh["boo"]]: Ugh["boo"][P] extends Ugh ? Ugh["boo"][P] : string })
};

const q: Ugh = { boo: {}, baz: {}};
const v: Ugh = {boo: { why: { boo: {}, baz: {}}}, baz: { why: { boo: {}, baz: {}} }};
```

The only difference is in the type of `boo`. Why doesn't the second one compile?

Comment: The first one is equivalent to `type Ugh = {  boo: { [s: string]: Ugh; };  baz: {  [x: string]: Ugh;  }; }`; concrete conditional types will be eagerly evaluated.  If you can explain your use case somewhere maybe we can suggest a type that works for what you're trying to do.  It is likely that you will have to make `Ugh` generic.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it's interesting that the title of this is "recursive generics" when there are no generics in your code.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't the second one compile?

The type `string | Ugh` does not extend the type `Ugh`, so in your second example, `Ugh["boo"][P] extends Ugh` will always be `false`, with the result that `baz` will always be of type `string`.

Here it is in code comments ([and in the playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/?noImplicitThis=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAqg5gCygXigbwFBW1A9LqAFQWgGdgAnASwDs4paATCADylEigHsAzWRAHRCsOAEZcuALnQicOANqlp5anQC6yyrTiyoAXwA0u0QEMAXtIAUuuZjn2c+KAFsIJmqXYITwKAAUoAHcqABsQqBMQwJMQT1Fod34EIQEbBzwCQIQqAGMkRi4IT1ZgCBpGJJS0h3kA2igAawgQXiT5ACJxLna1DTbOiR7atSgSssZPeARq+yd3CtIuLypPYLCIqJjPCiKuEIA3aGAlxKnU9PsAfn6uob81GblNVR0LvV0ASgw9AG4MDA4RwAjCgboM1IotOpRixSuVJogoNdKABXaDSHiRUgQH4ZdgUNH-QFJQgSUF2RwEYhkKH0JisdjgaCtFTaKAAHxJEiqci60jQUEUz20fVZdA5XKWhmM5isFIcTlc7k8wG8vgCa3CkWisSg8QiUDF9E5U1JXB56ScWVy+UKnhoXF8Y3KkotNTqNEazVapokHVuvWkvq4-vBwxhcImkpm12Doe6EPuMzmLsWy1WoS1m11O0WByOJ0NtPO6WFdF0ei+vyJTPYACZQXGBgnIS8Rs6o8Gkfi0VAMVicXjMSFsTXOMAAMyggAiPmgHc8s9K3dR6Kgw+xuKcq4BteAABZQUaJUv57Dxou5yuCWuN4OnHfd+OAKxH2knq8Losva+9-sj+8CDvIA)):

```
type Ugh = {
    // The string index type of Ugh...
    boo: {
        [s: string]: string
    },
    baz: (
        {
            // means that P will always be an Ugh...
            // which does extend Ugh...
            [P in keyof Ugh["boo"]]: Ugh["boo"][P] extends Ugh
            // and so this will always resolve to an Ugh.
            ? Ugh["boo"][P]
            : string
        }
    )
};

type t1 = Ugh["boo"][string] extends Ugh ? true : false; // true

type UghToo = {
    // The string index type of string | UghToo...
    boo: { [s: string]: string | UghToo },
    baz: ({
        // means that P will always be a string | UghToo...
        // which does not extend UghToo...
        [P in keyof UghToo["boo"]]: UghToo["boo"][P] extends UghToo
        ? UghToo["boo"][P]
        // and so this will always resolve to a string.
        : string
    })
};

type t2 = UghToo["boo"][string] extends UghToo ? true : false; // false
```

Generally, the union of two types (with few exceptions) does not extend either of those types.

```
type t3 = Date extends Date ? true : false; // true
type t4 = string | Date extends Date ? true : false; // false
type t5 = string | Date extends string ? true : false; // false
```

Comment: Awesome catch! Is there any way to accomplish the goal (discriminating based on type) without the union? Thanks for your help!

Comment: There might be a way to achieve your goal without the union; I suggest putting that follow up question into a new StackOverflow question, because that will keep this question's scope tight, and will also increase the chance of getting a answer to your follow up question.